# issues with amp-consent and onUpdateHref

Tags: amp-html

We are seeing some strange behaviour when using amp-consent.

`onUpdateHref` does not seem to be making a correct CORs request. Our code is setup to only accept CORs requests, but the `onUpdateHref`  request is failing, as it seems that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not being set. We are also not seeing the `__amp_source_origin` querystring. Both of these are being set on checkConsentHref, which is being called correctly with the CORs restriction.. If I remove the CORs restriction, the end point gets called, but I don't see any post data.